# regex to detect MathML in textarea in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, mathml

I'm using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and trying to create my own version of the [mode-changing demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/changemode.html). I have a `<textarea>` on which I listen for changes and when there is a change, I want to look at the value in the `<textarea>` and determine if it is in the form of MathML.

So I just need to a very crude/hackish way to detect if the value in the `<textarea>` is MathML; it doesn't have to be perfect. I'm thinking that I can run a regex when the `<textarea>` changes and look for any of the following tags:

```
<mfrac>
<msup>
<msub>
<msqrt>
<mroot>
<mfenced>
<msubsup>
<munderover>
<munder>
<mtable>
<mtr>
<mtd>
<mrow>
<mi>
<mo>
```

I need to take the string from the `<textarea>` and look if any of these tags are a substring. How would I write this regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/<m(?:frac|sup|sub|sqrt|root|fenced|subsup|underover|under|table|tr|td|row|i|o)\b/
```

will identify the start of any such tag.

To find a whole well-formed tag, you need to look for attributes before the closing `>` which is tougher.  Something like

```
/<m(?:frac|sup|sub|sqrt|root|fenced|subsup|underover|under|table|tr|td|row|i|o)\b[^>]*>/
```

is not guaranteed to match a whole tag, but will make sure there is a `>` after the start of the tag.

EDIT:

> ... what is /]*>/?

The regular expression has to be inside `/.../` the same way a string has to be inside quotes because that is how the JavaScript interpreter tells a regular expression literal from a string or a number or any other kind of token.

The `<m` matches the first two characters of any mathml tag.  The `(?:` and `)` form a non-capturing group.  It's the same as parentheses in an arithmetic expression.  In the same way you have to use parentheses in `(a + b) * (c + d)` I use parentheses above to distinguish `<m(?:frac|sup)` from `<mfrac|sup`.  The latter would match both `"<mfrac"` and `"sup"` without a `<m` before it.

The `\b` at the end is a word break.  It says that there shouldn't be another word character after the name.  So `<msub\b` matches `"<msub"` but not `"<msubmarine"`.

The `[^>]*` bit matches any number of characters other than `'>'`.  The `[...]` is a character set, so `[a-z]` matches any lower-case roman letter.  The `^` negates it, so `[^a-z]` matches any character that is not a lower-case roman letter.

Comment: I understand the middle is matching any of those tags beginning with the letter `m`, but can you explain the beginning and ending of that regex? so like, what is `/<m(?:` and `\b[^>]*>/`?

Comment: @Hristo, Edited the post with an explanation.